# Compiling module using linux source on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

04.2, 4.8.0-36-generic kernel, I'm failing to compile a module using only linux headers because of missing files that are included in the kernel source, I've downloaded the kernel source using `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`

> Makefile

```
obj-m+=modyy.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

> content of /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build

```
$ ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39  27 14:37 /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
```

> Compilation failure

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers is missing; modules have no dependencies and modversions.
```

I tried to create link from `/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build` the kernel source `/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.8.0`
but it compilation failed, Is that the correct method to compile using the kernel source?

How can I compile the module using the kernel source?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the compilation failure?

Comment: Did you install kernel headers package: something like `linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic ` https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic ? You simply can't use symlink to kernel source, as the source have no configuration files needed to build the modules to the current kernel (And it is hard to recreate needed configs exactly for your kernel).

Answer (score 0):

Don't create symlink to full kernel sources, just install kernel headers package with name like `linux-headers` or `linux-headers-generic`. For 4.8.0-36-generic kernel this is `linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic` package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic

```
 sudo unlink /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
```

You can also install `dkms` which will install everything needed to build linux kernel modules: `sudo apt-get install dkms`

Symlink from build to full kernel source will not help, as the full source tree have no configuration files needed to build modules for the current kernel, they are hard to generate to get compatible modules for kernel which was build by someone else. Just use "headers" package from the same person.